# Outputting value of xsl:variable with xsl:value-of problem

Tags: xslt, variables, value-of

I think I may have a misunderstanding of `<xsl:variable\>` and `<xsl:value-of\>` so perhaps someone can correct me!

I'm attempting to tweak some hardcoded banners to be a bit cleaner so I thought it would be a good idea to create an `<xsl:variable>` containing the banner link and image code, then use `<xml:value-of>` at the various places where the banner is needed. For example:

```
<!-- Global variable in my xslt file. There are a bunch of these... -->
<xsl:variable name="banner1">
    <a href="http://www.link.com/" title="Title" target="_blank">
        <img width="120" height="506" src="/images/banners/image.gif" alt="alt" />
    </a>
</xsl:variable>

<!-- Then when used: -->
<xsl:when test="blah'">
    <xsl:value-of select="$banner1"/>
</xsl:when>
```

But this isn't producing the output I expect. The images path etc is valid, but this just spits out nothing at all. Any text added before or after the `<a>` tag appears correctly, but nothing between the `<a>` tags Themselves.

What have I misunderstood about `<xsl:variable>` and how could I do this better (other than doing it "properly" and pulling adverts from a database etc. which I'd prefer...).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value you are selecting with xsl:value-of is the string value of the variable.

You want `<xsl:copy-of select='$banner1' />` to copy the result tree fragment.

Comment: Thankyou muchly! Pretty new to xsl and I wasn't seeing what I should have been doing differently. Cheers!